# Android tv box app development

Tags: android

Hi guy I have an android tv box (kitkat 4.4). I have some knowledge about android mobile app development. But I need to develop a app for tv box. Is there anyone who can guid me to do it. Example : what is the environment that I should have for android tv box app develop. Like that.
Thank you

Comment: try reading documentation

Comment: Is it different from android tv app and android tv box app.

Answer (score 1):

As i asked it is a android tv box(android 4.4 kitkat) not a android tv. Minimum requirements for android TV app android 5.0. But We can install mobile app in android tv box. I tried it and it works. Thanks you guys for your help

Comment: How you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Most Android TV Box is just use the same system for smartphones and tablets.
so just develop the app as you do for tablets (which have a wide screen).
just be careful with auto rotation. (might be you need to fix it as landscape)